# Retrieve information of update query magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to retrieve information of:

```
$query = 'update customer_entity set is_active=1 where email = "'.$email.'";';
$results = $writeConnection->query($query);
```

If print the value of $results i have a big result, but for example if I execute this query in mysql I have something like this:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

How can I get the information of query?.

Thanks.

Comment: Your answer don't solve my problem. I use a try-catch block

Comment: Please share that in asnwer

Answer (score 0):

> Single row update

```
SET @update_id := 0;
UPDATE some_table SET column_name = 'value', id = (SELECT @update_id := id)
WHERE some_other_column = 'blah' LIMIT 1; 
SELECT @update_id;
```

> Multiple rows updated

```
SET @uids := null;
UPDATE footable
   SET foo = 'bar'
 WHERE fooid > 5
   AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', fooid, @uids) );
SELECT @uids;
```

[Solution 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql)

[Solution 2](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/528) - `for Magento`